# react-color Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-color

(Kind of new in react) Im trying to implement react-color as a functional component in a project but im not being able to change the color.
all displays nicely but when I try to change color I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

I tried changing to a class component instead and it worked kind of better but I also get a very similar error. Some ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
import {FieldUpdating} from './FieldUpdating';
import {FieldUpdateError} from './FieldUpdateError';
import {ColorBox} from '../components/ColorBox';
import {ChromePicker} from 'react-color';

export function ColorEditor({label, value, setValue, updating, updateError}) {

return (
<div className="label-input mb-2 form-group">
  <label>{label}:</label>
  {value} //tried to get the value that displays as a string hex (hex string displays correct)
    <ChromePicker
      color={value}
      value={value}
      onChange={e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  <input value={value}/>

  {updating && <FieldUpdating />}
  {updateError && <FieldUpdateError error={updateError} />}
  <ColorBox color={value} />
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: in the onChange, try to `console.log(e)` instead of `setValue(e.target.value)` to see if the event contains a correctly looking target. update your question with the information you find.

Comment: In the ChromePicker `onchange`, `e.target` seems to be undefined, have you tried `console.log` e ?

Comment: It's a very specific error which tells you exactly what the problem is. `e.target` is `undefined`, so whatever `e` is, it has no `.target` property. According to the docs there's an `onChangeComplete` property that expects a function with a `color` parameter. You could just try `setValue(e)` for now.

Comment: with console.log(e) it seems to work fine, I can move arround the colors and dont get any errors plus I see all the hex values in console, but i can't set the color value when Im done. maybe I should create an "onClose" function? and say that on close setValue? Thanks for so fast answers!!! :)

Comment: Can you add the console output to the question? It's crucial here. Because if you just see hex color strings and not objects, the problem is obvious: a string doesn't have a `.target`, much less a `.target.value`.

Comment: @ChrisG yes! now it seems to be working right!!! thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: ahhh I see! now im geting exactly what @ChrisG was saying... "react-dom.development.js:14816 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {hsl, hex, rgb, hsv, oldHue, source}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just doing it wrong. Apparently you're trying to access `e.target.value`, while `e` returns something like :

```
{
  "hsl": {
    "h": 0,
    "s": 0.5626318818338767,
    "l": 0.648956228956229,
    "a": 1
  },
  "hex": "#d87373",
  "rgb": {
    "r": 216,
    "g": 115,
    "b": 115,
    "a": 1
  },
  "hsv": {
    "h": 0,
    "s": 0.46666666666666656,
    "v": 0.8464646464646465,
    "a": 1
  },
  "oldHue": 0,
  "source": "rgb"
}
```

So basically what you need to do is access`e.hex` like the following :

```
<ChromePicker
      color={value}
      value={value}
      onChange={e => {
        setValue(e.hex);
      }}
    />
```

Or like (use destructuring):

```
<ChromePicker
      color={value}
      value={value}
      onChange={({hex}) => {
        setValue(hex);
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Aaaaand you nailed it!!!! Thanks a lot everyone!!!! :) I learn something new today thanks to you all!